# Как сделать определенный внешний вид кнопок?

Tags: c#

Например как сделать вот такие кнопки, чтобы они выглядели так?[image]

Где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Не хватает балов что-бы оставить комментарий под вопросом. О какой платформе идёт речь? WinForms или WPF. Если еще не начали делать интерфейс, то лучше сделать это на WPF, там такие вещи делаются легко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать свой компонент наследованный от `Button`. Но еще один вариант это использовать `CheckBox`. Для этого необходимо установить свойство `Appearance` в `Button`. И поиграться со свойствами `FlatStyle` (установить в `Popup`, наиболее похоже на мой взгляд) и `FlatAppearance`.

Answer (score 1):

[Создание второго оконного приложения в C#](http://esate.ru/page/sozdanie-menu-i-zagryzka-izobrageniy-v-c-sharp) - посмотрите эту ссылку, надеюсь, она поможет вам.